# Close parent popup window from child popup window?

Tags: javascript

I have my web app with two popup windows parent and child
Sometimes the child  popup can be opened directly from the main application

when user open the child popup from the parent popup, I would like to close the parent popup (if the child was called from the main application then close nothing)

So the parent code to open the child popup looks like so:
the window.open then window.close(); to close the parent
The reason my code is in a table on click because its a fancy button.

```
<TABLE id="openChild" class="clsButton" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width="31px" 
onclick="window.open('www.google.com','child title','width=950,height=500');window.close();" onselectstart="return false;" ondblclickFunc="" stateful="false">
   table content
 </TABLE>
```

For some reason this closes both parent and child
Any idea why?

Comment: Looks like "window.close()" target all the popups on window. You should find a ways target specific popup (parent) using id.

Comment: but why isn't it running on the current context (parent popup window)

Comment: window is global object, doesnt matter from where you call it will refer to root.